# How can i set Android:Debuggable false

Tags: android, debugging, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I want change debuggable properties to false.

```
BuildConfig.DEBUG
```

This line always return true.

i tried add

`Android:debuggable false` in **androidmanifest.xml** but nothing change.

and i tried add in gradle files.

```
  buildTypes {
debug {
    debuggable true
    buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "true"
}

    release {
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "false"
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

But nothing changed again.

**My apk should be not debuggable.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this value shows that you have run your application in debug mode. it will be false when you generate a signed apk that will be of `release` build type.

actually you can use this value to see if the application is running in debugging state (by you while developing you application) or is being used by a user through a signed apk release.