# How to disable/remove stack trace calls from release app in android?

Tags: android, proguard, stack-trace, android-proguard, printstacktrace

I want to remove all stack trace calls from my application. Do I need to manually remove them or it can be directly removed from proguard or any other way?

Comment: what do you mean by `stack trace calls`?

Comment: calls which we write while handling exceptions like e.printstacktrace()

Comment: add debuggable false. follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363767/how-can-i-set-androiddebuggable-false

Comment: Thanks @hasan_shaikh but stack trace are still visible in logcat after debuggable false

Comment: Did you follow the above link which I mentioned? Because it is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proguard to remove usage of `printStackTrace` in your code. Add this rule to your proguard file:

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.lang.Throwable {
    public *** printStackTrace();
}
```